# php and uploading word and powerpoint

Tags: php, upload

i would like to upload Microsoft word  and power point documents  using php. the code below is working for images but i want it to work with word and power-point document. how do i change it?.  is it also possible to display the documents on a webpage so that other users can download them (create a download link).

```
    <?php

   $file = $_FILES['file_upload'];
   $name = $file['name'];
   $type = $file['type'];
   $tmp_location = $file['tmp_name'];
   $upload = 'uploads';
   $final_destination = $upload.'/'.$name;
   $error = $file['error'];
   $max_upload_size = 2097152;
   $size = $file['size'];

   $allowedImageTypes = array('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', );

   function imageTypeAllowed($imageType){
   global $allowedImageTypes;
   if(in_array($imageType, $allowedImageTypes))
    {
    return true;
    }

    else
    {
    return false;
    }
    }

   //Check for errors
   if($error > 0 || is_array($error)){
   die("Sorry an error occured");
   }

  //Check if file is image
  //Only required if image is only whjat we need
  if(!getimagesize($tmp_location)){
  die("Sorry, you can only upload image types");
  }

  if(!imageTypeAllowed($type)){
  die("Sorry, file type is not allowed");
  }

  if(file_exists($final_destination)){
  $final_destination = $upload.'/'.time().$name;
  }

  if(!move_uploaded_file($tmp_location, $final_destination)){
  die("Cannot finish upload, something went wrong");
  }

  ?>

  <h2>File Successfully uploaded!</h2>
```

Comment: *"is it also possible to display the documents on a webpage so that other users can download them"* --- You would need a seperate function for this, using the [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) function as well as other functions listed on that page, along with an `<a href="xxx">...</a>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add the MIME types of Powerpoint and Word inside your `$allowedImageTypes` array as follows:

```
$allowedImageTypes = array(
    'image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' , 
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation' 
);
```

For a whole list of MIME types of Office documents, refer to [this link](http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php).

Then, you need to remove the following validation:

```
// You should remove this block of code....
if(!getimagesize($tmp_location)) {
    die("Sorry, you can only upload image types");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your second question:

> *"is it also possible to display the documents on a webpage so that other users can download them (create a download link)"*

(*since Shankar [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22425819/) the first part*):

You can use something like this using the [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) function:

Sidenote: Replace `*.doc` with `*.*` if you wish to show all the files in the preferred folder.

```
$directory = "path/to/files/";
$files = glob($directory . "*.doc");

foreach($files as $file)
{
    echo '<a href="'.basename($file).'">'.$file.'</a>';
}
```

You can replace `'.$file.'` with the word "Download" for the word to appear as the link.

To limit certain file extensions, use:

```
$files = glob($directory . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,doc,ppt}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

which would resemble:

```
$directory = "path/to/folder/"; // keep the trailing slash, important
// $files = glob($directory . "*.jpg"); // limit .jpg files only

// show files of a certain extension only
$files = glob($directory . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,doc,ppt}', GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($files as $file)
{
    echo '<a href="'.basename($file).'">'.$file.'</a>' . "<br>";

// OPTIONAL methods - Uncomment the one you wish to use
// or with the words View/Download file with path echo'ed
// echo '<a href="'.basename($file).'">View/Download file '.$file.'</a>' . "<br>";

// or with the words View/Download file with no echo'ed path
// echo '<a href="'.basename($file).'">View/Download file</a>' . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the filename is already in the database, the link created for that file column will also be there (If not, add it manually).

Then, add the following code below `$file`, so that spaces in the filename are replaced with underscores (for example, `stack over flow screenshot.jpg` will be converted to `stack_over_flow_screenshot.jpg`):

```
$fileNameNew = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $name);
```

Now you can add the following to create a page for each member, where they can download the file:

```
<?php

/* Connect to database here */

$objTotalRS = mysql_query("select * from  tablename");

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($objTotalRS)) 
{
    ?>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>File Name :</td>
            <td><?= stripslashes($data['name']) ?></td>

            <td><a href="uploads/<?= $data['filenamenew'] ?>">Download Now</a></td> 
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?
}

?>
```

Also change the following line:

```
$final_destination = $upload.'/'.$name;
```

to:

```
$final_destination = $upload.'/'.$fileNameNew;
```